# Find tangent line to graph by computing a limit

Tags: calculus

Find the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)= 2x^2-x$ through (1,1). Do so by computing a limit, not by using a differentiation rule.

Comment: This exercise is FOR YOU.

Comment: user, what have you tried??

Comment: Welcome to Math.Se. Please provide some work on your question and tell us where you're stuck, without which there's no way anyone else can clear your query.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$\begin{align}
  f'(x) ~ = ~ & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \\
        ~ = ~ & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{2(x + h)^2 - (x + h) - (2x^2 - x)}{h} \\
        ~ = ~ & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{2(x^2 + 2xh + h^2) - (x + h) - (2x^2 - x)}{h} \\
        ~ = ~ & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{4xh + 2h^2 - h}{h} \\
        ~ = ~ & \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h(4x + 2h - 1)}{h}
\end{align}$$